# can't find graphviz module in azure notebook but says it's installed

Tags: python, azure, pip, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I installed graphviz in my jupyter notebook (Azure studio).
I know it is installed because when i try to install it again like this:

`!{sys.executable} -m pip install graphviz`

this is printed out:

```
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.14.1)
```

However, when I then try to import stuff from graphviz / use it / look for it:

`!type graphviz`

I get this:

```
graphviz: not found
```

I thought it might be a pathing problem but it doesn't seem to be:

`print(sys.path)` gives:

```
['/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python36.zip',  
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6',  
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',   
 '',
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages',   
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost-0.90-py3.6.egg',  
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',  
 '/home/azureuser/.ipython',   
 '/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_project/vendor']
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction? I am a little bit lost and have been trying to locate the issues for a while now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the command `!{sys.executable} -m pip install graphviz` you installed the python package [`graphiz`](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/).

You can use it in your python script by following the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz#quickstart).

As you're trying the command `!type graphviz` it seems you want to have the graphviz binary though, not the python package.

The [Graphviz download page](https://graphviz.org/download/) has install instructions for different operating systems, e.g.:

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

Alternatively you can install [Graphviz via conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz):

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```